# C# checkboxes need to have one item selected, if not then display a message to the users

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, checkbox

Morning folks,

I have the following checkbox area on my create.cshtml page in my c# mvc project.  I am using visual studio 2015 for my project.

I have a section on my web page that lists three options for the user in the form of checkboxes.   The user must select at least one of these items.

This is what code for the checkboxes looks like on my create.cshtml page....

```
             @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.carer.ParentResp, new { id = "rbParent" }))
             @Html.Label("rbParent", "Parental Responsibility")<br />
             @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.carer.NextOfKin, new { id = "rbNext" })
             @Html.Label("rbNext", "Next of Kin")<br />
             @Html.CheckBoxFor(model => model.carer.Keyholder, new { id = "rbKey" })
             @Html.Label("rbKey", "Keyholder?")
```

With the above code i have the following errors for all three items....

- Cannot convert lambda expression to intended delegate type because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type...
- Cannot implicitly convert type 'bool?' to 'bool'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)

In my database the three fields are set at data type bit and in my model within my mvc project, they are brought in using entity framework as data type bool.

I believe that in my controller, i need to check and see if these items are checked or not.

I have added this following code to my controller...

```
        //Do a check to see if the checkbox have a value
        if (carer.ParentResp.HasValue || carer.NextOfKin.HasValue || carer.Keyholder.HasValue)
        {
            vmPopulateData.carer = carer;
        }
        else 
        {
            ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.GetType(), "Message", "alert('" + "Please Select all check boxes that apply" + "');", true);
        }
```

Im simply wanting to check if any of the three check boxes have a value, if not then to display a message to the user.

I have seen many examples use a ClientScript.RegisterClientscriptBlock method, but i cannot get this to work.  I get the following error messages...

- The name 'ClientScript' does not exist in the current context
- The name 'Me' does not exist in the current context

Am i missing an namespace to register these items?

Im really struggeling to get this functionality working.  Any pointers or examples people have used previously would be welcomed.   Im not looking to do anything really clever or over engineering anything here.  Just looking for a simple validation element to check and see if a user has checked at least one item so the form can be submitted.

Regards
Betty

Comment: `ParentResp` etc are typeof `bool` - they do not have a `.HasValue` property (that is only applicable to a `bool?`). You ca just use `if (carer.ParentResp || carer.NextOfKin || ....`

Comment: And `ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock()` is webforms code and not applicable to MVC. You just add a `ModelStateError` and return the view to display the error message if none have been selected

Comment: You are trying to use a CheckBox as RadioButton. Why don't you just use RadioButtonFor  ?

Comment: You have said that the database fields are `BIT` and the model properties are `bool` - but I think you mean `bool?` (nullable)?

Comment: @ Ksv3n, I was under the impression that with a checkbox you have select multiple items and with the radio btn you are only able to select one?  My users need to select at least one option, but could select all three?

Comment: @StephenMuecke,  Yep, in my model they are all set to...  public Nullable<bool> NextOfKin { get; set; }  public Nullable<bool> ParentResp { get; set; }  public Nullable<bool> Keyholder { get; set; },  I was just a little confused as why I have an error message that states.... "Cannot implicity convert type bool? to bool?"

Comment: Because `CheckBoxFor()` can only bind to a `bool` (a checkbox has 2 states - on and off - `true` and `false`). A nullable `bool` has 3 states. You need to make you properties `bool`, not `bool?`

Comment: @StephenMuecke   brilliant.  Many thanks for that.  that is much help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can call your action method using ajax call and return validation message as json retrun.that may be the easiest way to show the script message.
Before you call your function you can validate the checkbox and collect the value and pass it to the action method using ajax

```
     $.ajax(this.href, {
  success: function(data) {
     $('#main').html($(data).find('#main *'));
     $('#notification-bar').text('The page has been successfully loaded');
  },
  error: function(err) {
     //show your error message
  }
  });
```